# Updating ArrayList with onlick not working

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I made an Arraylist which keeps the list of fruits and i want to update it whenever i click button. So i used onclick method on button and tried to add using EditText but an error popped up saying can't resolve add symbol.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
    fruits.add("apple");
    fruits.add("banana");
    fruits.add("mango");
    fruits.add("orange");
    fruits.add("peach");

    ListAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,fruits);
    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mylist.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String fruit = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,fruit,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

    );


}

public void onClick (View view) {
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String name = input.getText().toString();
    fruits.add(name);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've two arrayList one local and another one global.

`onClick()` method you're adding your item in global arrayList having reference name fruits but your ListView using local arrayList also having same name fruits, so don't create local list inside `onCreate()` method. Also after adding new fruit call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

```
ArrayList<String> fruits;
ListAdapter myAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
    fruits.add("apple");
    fruits.add("banana");
    fruits.add("mango");
    fruits.add("orange");
    fruits.add("peach");

    myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,fruits);
    ....
}

public void onClick (View view) {
   final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   String name = input.getText().toString();
   fruits.add(name);
   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, your fruits ArrayList is a local variable visible only within onCreate() method.

first you need to declare fruits outside onCreate() method.
second, after adding to fruits ArrayList, you must call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to reflect the changes in listview.

let me know if this works!!

Comment: actually, notifyDataSetChanged() method does not work and notify() method makes app crash

Answer (score 0):

You needs to define fruits arraylist outside of onCreate method. It should be property to the main activity.